# AWS Chime mute and unmute joined attendee

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

guys!

I need some information about AWS Chime SDK (amazon-chime-sdk-js)

Does the Amazon Chime SDK have the following capability:
3 participants (Anna, John and Lenny) are connected to the metting room and Anna wants to ignore Lenny's microphone and hear only John, but John hears both Anna and Lenny and Lenny hears Anna and John, Anna hears only John and ignored Lenny's audio(voice)

https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-js

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the latest chime SDK until 2.6.2.

Chime audio is centrally mixed and there is no way until now to split the audio to be able to achieve this.

https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-js/issues/632

https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-js/issues/933

Answer (score 0):

This service (AWS Chime SDK) really does not solve my problem.
I was able to resolve my issue through the Agora service.

Thanks for all!